# Get Cesium, SystemJS, and Angular2 to work?

Tags: angular, typescript, systemjs, cesiumjs

Does somebody have a working example where SystemJS (not Webpack) is being used with an Angular2 (in TypeScript, not Dart) with Cesium (npm)?

I am aware of this blog post on cesiumjs' site:
https://cesiumjs.org/2016/01/26/Cesium-and-Webpack/

And I like how the author says, "You can't simply do a `require('cesium')`."  The problem with the article is that it uses the Webpack way, and I do not have that available.

Either way, I am looking to solve this particular error (from the Browser):
`Error: (SystemJS) AMD module http://localhost:3000/node_modules/cesium/Build/CesiumUnminified/Cesium.js did not define`

Here's what I have:

In my `systemjs.config.js` file:

```
paths: {'npm:' :  'node_modules/'},
map: {
    // our app is within the dist folder
    app: 'dist',

    // angular bundles
    '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
    ...

    'require': 'npm:requirejs/require.js',
    'cesium': 'npm:cesium/Build/CesiumUnminified/Cesium.js',

    // Other packages
    ...
}
```

`@Injectable()` Example:

```
let Cesium = require('cesium');
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()

export class CesiumClock {
    private _start:any = Cesium.JulianDate.now();
    private _stop:any = Cesium.JulianDate.addHours(this._start,12,new Cesium.JulianDate());
    private _clock:any = new Cesium.Clock({
        startTime: this._start,
        stopTime: this._stop,
        currentTime: this._start,
        clockRange: Cesium.ClockRange.LOOP_STOP,
        mutliplier: 1,
        shouldAnimate: true
    });
}
```

And finally, the client code that tries to use my 'CesiumClock', and gives me the error (after transpiling) in the browser:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CesiumClock } from '../services/index';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id.replace("/dist", "/app"),
    templateUrl: 'stuff.component.html',
    styleUrls: [
        'stuff.css',
        'node_modules/cesium/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css'
    ]
 })

export class StuffComponent {
    constructor(private _cesiumClock:CesiumClock) {}
}
```

**UPDATE**:

Based on `@artem`'s answer, I was able to remove the specific 'Error: (SystemJS) AMD' from the browser.  But now, if I want to refer to anything Cesium, such `new Cesium.Viewer(...)` the `Cesium` object is just a blank slate.  The error I see is

`Cesium.Viewer is not a constructor`

Comment: Sorry to interrupt, but for future viewers. Just use https://github.com/tgftech/angular-cesium

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @artem for opening my eyes on this.  Here's my final answer that works for me:

**systemjs.config.js** (See `'cesium'` under `packages` and note the global variable, `CESIUM_BASE_URL`)

```
(function(global){
    global.CESIUM_BASE_URL = './node_modules/cesium/Build/CesiumUnminified';
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        map: {
            ...
            // paths serve as alias
            'cesium': 'npm:cesium/Build/CesiumUnminified'
            ...
        },
        packages: {
            ...
            'cesium': {
                main: './Cesium.js',
                meta: {
                    '*.js': {
                        format: 'cjs'
                    }
                }
            },
            ...
        }
    });
})(this);
```

**cesium.viewer.ts** (Note the combined `declare` and `import` statements.  The declare allows the typescript compiler to know about `Cesium`.  The import statement is that it works in the browser.):

```
declare var Cesium:any;
import 'cesium';

@Injectable()
export class CesiumViewer {
    ...
    this._viewer = new Cesium.Viewer(elem, {...});
    ...
}
```

I believe, the `meta` part helps because Cesium actually needs a boatload of .js files.  Without the `meta` `*.js` property, it only grabs Cesium.js, which is not enough, regardless of minification or not, Source or not.

Now, I've got a major CSS crisis.  The Cesium map is a giant mess of junk in the browser.

Comment: Not working for me yet :-/ I do get the error `EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: Unable to process binding "click: function (){return function(){ cameraClicked.raiseEvent(this);} }"
Message: n(...).bind is not a function
TypeError: Unable to process binding "click: function (){return function(){ cameraClicked.raiseEvent(this);} }"
Message: n(...).bind is not a function`   any idea?

Comment: @mfreiholz - I think you might have a separate question.  I would post a question, and if you think it would help, link this one in regards to your setup?  If our questions are duplicates, somebody will surely note it.

Answer (score 2):

SystemJS auto-detects format for `CesiumUnminified/Cesium.js` as `amd`, but for whatever reason it does not work as amd module with SystemJS. It can be loaded if you set its format to CommonJS, that is:

```
    map: {
         ...
        'cesium': 'npm:cesium/Build/CesiumUnminified',
```

and

```
    packages: {
            ...
        cesium: {
            main: 'Cesium.js',
            format: 'cjs'
        },
```

**Update** it looks like SystemJS is unable to use both versions provided in `node_modules/cesium/Build`: mapping to either `Cesium` or `CesiumUnminified` in `Build` results in `import Cesium = require('cesium');` returning an empty object.

However, it can be loaded from the sources provided in `node_modules/cesium/Source`. When I remove `format: 'cjs'` from `cesium` package and change mapping to `'cesium': 'npm:cesium/Source'`, I can get this code

```
 import Cesium = require('cesium');
 console.dir(Cesium.Viewer);
```

to print

```
 function Viewer(container, options)
```

in the console. No idea if it will actually work though.

Comment: I wanted to give you the green check, but I didn't get a chance to test it until today.  Thank you!

Comment: So, this solved the error I was getting, but it did not make Cesium use-able in my @Components.  Cesium.Viewer is undefined, Cesium.someFunctionThatIsDefined is not a function.

Comment: Yes, the format for `Cesium.js` in `Build` does not look familiar to me, I'm not sure if it's supported by SystemJS. However I can load populated `cesium` object from `node_modules/cesium/Source`, no idea how useful it is. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got Cesium to work with Angular 2 and SystemJS by using a slightly different config, as the answers above didn't work for me.

**systemjs.config.js:**

```
(function (global) {
  global.CESIUM_BASE_URL = './node_modules/cesium/Build/CesiumUnminified';
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
     ...
     'cesium': 'npm:cesium/Build/CesiumUnminified'
     ...
},
// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
packages: {
  ...
  'cesium': {
    main: './Cesium.js',
    meta: {
      '*.js': {
        format: 'global'
      }
    }
  }
}
});
})(this);
```

And this in **app.component.js**:

```
import 'cesium';
```